# Find recent checkouts in Clearcase and feed file paths to xlsvtree to view file history

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, clearcase

My goal is to query a certain VOB and developer, find files he/she modified from X date and pass them one by one to the version tree program.

Here I can list all of my work since 20th November:
`cleartool find /vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim -version "{created_by(egronei) && created_since(20-Nov-12)}" -print`

Output of which is:

```
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddBatchTreeComponent.java@@/main/dev/o13.2_ld/1
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.oss.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddBatchTreeComponent.java@@/main/dev/o13.2_ld/0
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.oss.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddNodeTabBase.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/1
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.oss.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddNodeTabBase.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/0
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddNodeTreeComponent.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/1
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/AddNodeTreeComponent.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/0
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/ResultsTab.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/1
/vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim/common-src/client/plugins/com.bsim.ui/src/main/java/com/bsim/ui/tabs/addnode/common/ResultsTab.java@@/main/at_ossrc_dev/dev/o13.2_ld/0
```

I can use grep to filter a line and pass only that file path to version tree, but ideally I'd like it to beer somehow and pipe the file names over one by one (for code review). Here's my grep attempt:
`cleartool find /vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_bsim -version "{created_by(egronei) && created_since(20-Nov-12)}" -print | grep -i "language.properties" | xlsvtree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to pass a file found with a `cleartool find` is to use the `$CLEARCASE_PN` variable:

```
ct find ... -exec 'cleartool lsvtree "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

you can find an example in this [IBM page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425):

> To find all elements with any label:
>   UNIX/Linux:

```
cleartool find . -type f -exec 'cleartool lsvtree -a $CLEARCASE_PN' | grep "("

./hello.c@@/main/1 (LABEL100, LABEL99, LABEL98, LABEL97)
./foo.xml@@/main/BR1/1 (REL2)
./bar.o@@/main/1 (REL1)
```

Using that same mechanism (`$CLEARCASE_PN`), you can instead drop that list in a file and process that file (easier than processing it directly from the find command).